# Error while compiling Angular Project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am new to Angular and I am trying to build a project.I am getting a weird error while compiling an angular project.I have wasted a lot of time trying to find a solution.Can anyone please help.
I am using following versions:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.4
Node: 8.9.4
OS: linux x64
Angular: 4.3.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, tsc-wrapped

@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.11
@angular/cli: 1.6.4
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.11
@angular/service-worker: 1.0.0-beta.16
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.38
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.25
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.48
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.13
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.13
typescript: 2.3.4
webpack-bundle-analyzer: 2.9.0
webpack: error
```

Following is Error:

```
    ERROR in ./src/app/feed/feed.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: Can't resolve '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' in '/home/praveen/loklak_search/src/app/feed'
    at onError (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:61:15)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at /home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:40:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at innerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:144:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:249:35)
    at resolver.doResolve.createInnerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:44:6)
 @ ./src/app/feed/feed.component.ts 144:17-49
 @ ./src/app/feed/feed.module.ts
 @ ./src/$$_gendir lazy
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./src/app/feed/feed-header/feed-header.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: Can't resolve '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' in '/home/praveen/loklak_search/src/app/feed/feed-header'
    at onError (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:61:15)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at /home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:40:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at innerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:144:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:249:35)
    at resolver.doResolve.createInnerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:44:6)
 @ ./src/app/feed/feed-header/feed-header.component.ts 83:17-56
 @ ./src/app/feed/feed.module.ts
 @ ./src/$$_gendir lazy
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./src/app/home/home.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: Can't resolve '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' in '/home/praveen/loklak_search/src/app/home'
    at onError (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:61:15)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at /home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:40:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at innerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:144:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:249:35)
    at resolver.doResolve.createInnerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:44:6)
 @ ./src/app/home/home.component.ts 90:17-49
 @ ./src/app/home/home.module.ts
 @ ./src/$$_gendir lazy
 @ ./node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"import":false}!./node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles/main.scss
Module build failed: Error: Can't resolve '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' in '/home/praveen/loklak_search/src/styles'
    at onError (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:61:15)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at /home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:40:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at innerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:144:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:249:35)
    at resolver.doResolve.createInnerCallback (/home/praveen/loklak_search/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:44:6)
 @ ./src/styles/main.scss 4:14-224
 @ multi ./src/styles/main.scss
```

Anyone please help I have searched a lot for solutions online but nowhere I am getting the solution.Is something I am missing which is needed to be installed.

Comment: Have you Angular-Material something like this `prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css` in it ?

Comment: the error seems pretty clear, `material themes` cannot be resolved. Please check your folder structure and make sure the relevant files are available. Do a file refresh in your IDE just to make sure.

Comment: It is an open source project which I have forked and cloned it on my local machine,I am unable to build it.It is compiling successfully on other developers' machine.Here is a link to the project  https://github.com/fossasia/loklak_search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because they are attempting to import a .css file into a .scss file inside the main.scss file. It seems like they have followed the guide [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme)

You can remove this reference from main.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

and add it under the styles attribute in the angular-cli.json like:

```
"styles": [
    "styles/main.scss",
    "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self explanatory :

```
ERROR in ./src/app/feed/feed.component.scss
Error: Can't resolve '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' in ['...']
```

This means your CSS file isn't found.

To resolve that :

- Check that the file is actually here
- If not, reinstall the package with `npm install`
- If it is there, check that the path provided is correct
- check the file extension